# Custom User Control Button Backgroundcolor changes on ShowDialog

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I am writing a custom user control library in .NET 4.5.2 with WPF.
My custom Button behaves very strange and I am really desperate by now. First of all, here's the project [GitHub](https://github.com/tom-unger/Cosmos)

**The Problem** 
Here is the MainWindow of a test-project with the custom Button
[image: MainWindow]
Click-Event Code

```
Window1 win1 = new Window1();
win1.ShowDialog();
```

XAML-Code

```
<Grid>
    <Cosmos:CButton x:Name="B1" 
                    C_BackgroundTheme="HKS41" 
                    HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
                    Margin="62,80,0,0" 
                    VerticalAlignment="Top" 
                    Width="117" 
                    Content="ShowDialog" 
                    Click="CButton_Click"/>
</Grid>
```

Nothing too special. Now I click the Button and the second Window opens as usually.

[image: Second Window]

XAML-Code

```
<Grid>
    <Cosmos:CButton C_BackgroundTheme="Red" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="83,100,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Content="Test 2"/>
    <Cosmos:CButton C_BackgroundTheme="HKS44" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="83,63,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Content="Test"/>
</Grid>
```

The Button from which the ShowDialog goes out, changes its Backgroundcolor to the one of the last button in the XAML code. In this case the lighter blue (HSK44), not the red.

**Code**

This is the CS-Code of the Custom Button:

```
public class CButton : Button
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty BackgroundThemeProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("C_BackgroundTheme", typeof(Theme), typeof(CButton), new PropertyMetadata(new PropertyChangedCallback(BackgroundValueChanged)));
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ForegroundThemeProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("C_ForegroundTheme", typeof(Theme), typeof(CButton), new PropertyMetadata(new PropertyChangedCallback(ForegroundValueChanged)));

    public static bool Backgroundchanged = false;

    private static string backcolor;
    private static string Backcolor
    {
        get { return backcolor; }
        set
        {
            backcolor = value;
            Backgroundchanged = true;
        }
    }

    static CButton()
    {
        DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(CButton), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(CButton)));
    }

    public Theme C_BackgroundTheme
    {
        get
        {
            return (Theme)GetValue(BackgroundThemeProperty);
        }
        set
        {
            SetValue(BackgroundThemeProperty, value);
        }
    }

    public Theme C_ForegroundTheme
    {
        get
        {
            return (Theme)GetValue(ForegroundThemeProperty);
        }
        set
        {
            SetValue(ForegroundThemeProperty, value);
        }
    }

    private static void BackgroundValueChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var control = (CButton)d;

        Backcolor = GetColorString((Theme)e.NewValue);

        control.Background = (SolidColorBrush)(new BrushConverter().ConvertFrom(Backcolor));
        control.OpacityMask = (SolidColorBrush)(new BrushConverter().ConvertFrom(ChangeColorBrightness((Color)ColorConverter.ConvertFromString(Backcolor), (float)-0.3).ToString()));
    }

    private static void ForegroundValueChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var control = (CButton)d;
        control.Foreground = GetColorBrush((Theme)e.NewValue);
    }

    public static Color ChangeColorBrightness(Color color, float correctionFactor)
    {
        float red = (float)color.R;
        float green = (float)color.G;
        float blue = (float)color.B;

        if (correctionFactor < 0)
        {
            correctionFactor = 1 + correctionFactor;
            red *= correctionFactor;
            green *= correctionFactor;
            blue *= correctionFactor;
        }
        else
        {
            red = (255 - red) * correctionFactor + red;
            green = (255 - green) * correctionFactor + green;
            blue = (255 - blue) * correctionFactor + blue;
        }

        return Color.FromArgb(color.A, (byte)red, (byte)green, (byte)blue);
    }

    protected override void OnMouseEnter(MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        Backcolor = this.Background.ToString();

        ColorAnimation colorChangeAnimation = new ColorAnimation
        {
            To = ChangeColorBrightness((Color)ColorConverter.ConvertFromString(Backcolor), (float)0.15),
            Duration = new Duration(new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 0, 100))
        };

        PropertyPath colorTargetPath = new PropertyPath("(Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)");
        Storyboard CellBackgroundChangeStory = new Storyboard();
        Storyboard.SetTarget(colorChangeAnimation, this);
        Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(colorChangeAnimation, colorTargetPath);
        CellBackgroundChangeStory.Children.Add(colorChangeAnimation);
        CellBackgroundChangeStory.Begin();
    }

    protected override void OnMouseLeave(MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        ColorAnimation colorChangeAnimation = new ColorAnimation
        {
            To = (Color)ColorConverter.ConvertFromString(Backcolor),
            Duration = new Duration(new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 0, 100))
        };

        PropertyPath colorTargetPath = new PropertyPath("(Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)");
        Storyboard CellBackgroundChangeStory = new Storyboard();
        Storyboard.SetTarget(colorChangeAnimation, this);
        Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(colorChangeAnimation, colorTargetPath);
        CellBackgroundChangeStory.Children.Add(colorChangeAnimation);
        CellBackgroundChangeStory.Begin();
    }

    protected override void OnClick()
    {
        Thread.Sleep(10);
        base.OnClick();
    }
}
```

And here is the ResourceDictionary

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Cosmos">

<Style TargetType="{x:Type local:CButton}">
    <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="/Cosmos;component/Fonts/#Circular Std Medium"/>
    <Setter Property="Content" Value="CButton"/>
    <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Left"/>
    <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Top"/>
    <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="True"/>
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#FFEEEEEE"/>
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FF111111"/>
    <Setter Property="Height" Value="32"/>
    <Setter Property="Width" Value="120"/>
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="14"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                <Grid>
                    <Border Name="outerborder"
                            BorderThickness="0,0,0,3"
                            BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding OpacityMask}"
                            CornerRadius="2"
                            Height="{TemplateBinding Height}">
                        <Border Name="outerbordertop"
                            BorderThickness="0,0,0,0"
                            BorderBrush="Transparent"
                            CornerRadius="2"
                            Height="{TemplateBinding Height}">
                            <Border Name="border"
                                BorderThickness="0,0,0,0"
                                CornerRadius="2"
                                Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                                VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
                                <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,1,0,0"/>
                            </Border>
                        </Border>
                    </Border>
                    <Rectangle Fill="{TemplateBinding OpacityMask}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="0,3,0,0"/>
                </Grid>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="true">
                        <Trigger.EnterActions>
                            <BeginStoryboard>
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ThicknessAnimation Duration="0:0:0.07" FillBehavior="HoldEnd" Storyboard.TargetName="outerborder" Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderThickness" To="0,0,0,0" />
                                    <ThicknessAnimation Duration="0:0:0.07" FillBehavior="HoldEnd" Storyboard.TargetName="outerbordertop" Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderThickness" To="0,3,0,0" />
                                </Storyboard>
                            </BeginStoryboard>
                        </Trigger.EnterActions>
                        <Trigger.ExitActions>
                            <BeginStoryboard>
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ThicknessAnimation Duration="0:0:0.07" FillBehavior="HoldEnd" Storyboard.TargetName="outerborder" Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderThickness" To="0,0,0,3" />
                                    <ThicknessAnimation Duration="0:0:0.07" FillBehavior="HoldEnd" Storyboard.TargetName="outerbordertop" Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderThickness" To="0,0,0,0" />
                                </Storyboard>
                            </BeginStoryboard>
                        </Trigger.ExitActions>
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Why does the Button behave like this? I am also happy about any tips related to the Code.

Comment: Have you tried setting `OverridesDefaultStyle` to true in your style? Also it might be the fact that the button doesn't call mouse leave until the dialog window is closed. Try it with default button and see if it happens as well.

Comment: @XAMlMAX Thats a good idea, I will try that real qick

Comment: @XAMlMAX Okay, so if there is a standard button in the second window with a green background, the custom button in the MainWIndow doesnt change anything on click. So it has to be a issue just between the custom buttons.

Comment: Try to apply the custom logic to the default button and see if the same issue arises. I am talking about mouse enter and leave event handlers.

Comment: Excuse me, I dont unterstand what you mean. I already inherit from the default button.

Comment: You have a default button, so use `OnMouseEnter(MouseEventArgs e)` `OnMouseLeave(MouseEventArgs e)` logic in your default button. Does that makes sense?

Comment: You mean that I should copy the custom mouseenter and mouseleave events to a default button? That should not work because it has no style that I could edit, `Backcolor` would not exist

Comment: Nope, I mean to subscribe to those events, like you can subscribe to the click event.

Comment: Like this `<Button Content="ShowDialog" Click="btnSave_Click" MouseEnter="btn_MouseEnter" MouseLeave="btn_MouseLeave">
        </Button>` and then in your code behind `private void btn_MouseEnter(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {

        }` Does that makes sense?

Comment: Okay so I subscribed to the `MouseEnter` and `MouseLeave` events of the default button. And now? The `MouseLeave` event gets called after the new window showed up when I click the button

Comment: Can you reproduce the issue with the colour of the control? What I mean is, does the colour changes for default button or is it only for the custom button.

Comment: Please note that there are naming conventions for dependency properties. The identifier field of a dependency property named `C_BackgroundTheme` (which is an odd name) should be named `C_BackgroundThemeProperty`. Besides that, what is the purpose of the static `Backcolor` field? If you really need it, it should not be static. Finally, you must never call Thread.Sleep in the UI thread, because it will block that thread and make your UI unresponsive.

Comment: @XAMlMAX It only happens with the custom button

Comment: Hey try by giving based on Basedon={staticresource Button}

Comment: To be honest with you, this entire button can be templated in XAML and entire code behind removed. All you do is applying `Foreground` and `Background` with an animation.